# How can I clear the contents of every file in a subdirectory without changing ownership / permissions?

Tags: linux, bash, find, pipe

I can find the list of files using something like:

`find /path/to/files -type f`

And I can clear the contents of a single file with any of:

`> filename`

`echo -n > filename`

`cat /dev/null > filename`

You can do something like this with commands that don't involve output redirection:

`find /path/to/files -type f -exec file '{}' \;`

However this does not work:

`find /path/to/files -type f -exec echo -n > '{}' \;`

I can't seem to construct a command using find's `-exec` or `| xargs` to pipe the file list into one of these commands that will clear the files. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find /path/to/files -type f -exec /bin/sh -c "> '{}'" ';'` should do what you want; see [find(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) for details on how exec works in detail, but this invocation runs the command once, putting the filename where `{}` is.

You can also tell xargs to only pass a single filename to the command, or use `find /path -type f | while read file; do echo -n > "$file"; done` to do that at the shell level.

Comment: I was trying something along the lines of your first example however it does not work. See my edit in the original question.

Comment: Sorry, I should have noticed that wouldn't work - I didn't think about it, just copied it from your example.  The update shows how to fix that; invoking a single shell command.  Using the "| while read file; do" version would also work smoothly.

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun, here's another option:

```
find /path/to/files -type f -exec dd if=/dev/null of={} \;
```

Comment: Nice! I was trying to think of a way to avoid the redirection.

Comment: This one works! Straightforward approach.

Comment: This was perfect for me.

Comment: Out of interest, what is `of={} \` doing here? I understand `of` is dd's output file, but the braces and the following backslash are what are throwing me off.

Comment: @Hashim The `{}` is part of the syntax for find's `-exec` primary; it basically means "put filepath/name here", so you get `of=path/to/file`. The backslash makes the shell pass the following `;` to `find` as an argument, rather than treating it as a delimiter ending the command. And the `;` is, again, part of the `-exec` syntax that indicates the end of the command to execute. Compare with @DanielPittman's answer, which uses `{}` the same way (but in a different context), and puts `;` in single-quotes (which has the same effect as escaping it).